# Title missing in the last subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, title, subplot, pyvisa

I have created subplots that contain measurements taken from an oscilloscope. 
N is a parameter that determines the number of subplots. 
The issue is that when there's 1 plot, it has no title or y label.
When there are more than one plot, only the last one is affected

```
##Plots a time trend of the active measurements on a MSO4/5/6
##Pierre Dupont - Tek - 2020

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import visa
import sys

rm = visa.ResourceManager()
scope = rm.open_resource('TCPIP::192.168.1.34::INSTR')

##determines number of active measurements
def active_measurements():
    meas_list=scope.query('MEASUrement:LIST?')
    N=meas_list.count(",")+1
    if "NONE" in meas_list:
        scope.close()
        sys.exit("No measurement found, exiting...")
    return(N)

N=active_measurements()
plots_set={} ##dictionary that will contain the subplots. One per active measurement.
ydata_set={} ##dictionary that will contain the array of logged data
fig=plt.figure()
IDN=scope.query('*idn?')
fig.suptitle('Measurement data logger / connected to: '+IDN,fontsize=10,color='purple')
plt.style.use('ggplot')

##definition of the subplots in the dictionary + subplots titles and axis legend
for i in range (1,N+1):
    plots_set["ax"+str(i)]=fig.add_subplot(N,1,i)
    meas_type=scope.query('MEASUrement:MEAS{}:TYPe?'.format(i))
    plots_set["ax"+str(i)].set_title(meas_type,fontsize='small')
    meas_unit=scope.query('MEASUrement:MEAS{}:YUNIT?'.format(i))
    plots_set["ax"+str(i)].set_ylabel(meas_unit.replace('"',''))
    print(i,meas_type,meas_unit)
    ydata_set["y"+str(i)]=[]


index=0
x=[]

## function that runs at every data log. Appends the arrays of measurement 
## data and updates the subplots
def animate(i):
    global index
    index+=1
    x.append(index)
    t=1
    for k,k2 in zip(ydata_set,plots_set):
        scope.query('*OPC?')
        M=float(scope.query('MEASUrement:MEAS{}:RESUlts:CURRentacq:MEAN?'.format(t)))
        t+=1
        plt.cla()
        ydata_set[k].append(M)
        plots_set[k2].plot(x,ydata_set[k],marker="X",linewidth=0.5,color='blue')


##frames parameter = number of logs // interval parameter = time between 2 logs (in ms)
ani=FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=1000, interval=500, repeat=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

scope.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 RISETIME
 "s"

2 POVERSHOOT
 "%"

3 MAXIMUM
 "V"
```

[image: example, 3rd plot misses y label and title]

Many thanks for your inputs. Sorry for any lack of clarity that's my first post.

Comment: Please modify your code and add the missing variables so that we can test for ourselves.

Comment: Maybe `scope.query('MEASUrement:MEAS{}:TYPe?'.format(i))` returns an empty string for `i == N` ? Maybe you should use `.format(i-1)` ? Maybe you could print its value?  Clearly the data that can answer your question is not provided.

Comment: @JohanC thanks I've added a print to make sure no empty string is returned

Comment: `plt.cla()` erases the current ax. So, probably it is clearing the last ax. You would need to set the title again, or not erase that ax.

Comment: `for k,k2 in zip(ydata_set,plots_set):` and then using `ydata_set[k]` is absolutely not how Python works. It should be more something like `for k, ax in zip(range(len(ydata_set)), plots_set)` and then use it as `ydata_set[k].append(...)` and `ax.plot(...)`

Comment: To [remove the plot but not the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075614/in-matplotlib-how-can-i-clear-an-axes-contents-without-erasing-its-axis-labels): `for artist in ax.lines + ax.collections: artist.remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `plt.cla()` clears the current, in this case most recently created, axes. This will clear all lines, labels, title, etc. If you want to use `plt.cla()` in your animate function you will need to reset those each time, e.g.

```py
def animate(i):
    # ...
    plt.cla()
    plt.set_title("title")
    plt.set_ylabel("label")
    # etc
```

An alternative would be to use `set_data` to update your plots, i.e.

```py
lines = [subplot.plot(x, ydata, marker="X", linewidth=0.5, color='blue')[0] 
         for subplot, ydata in zip(plots_set, ydata)]
def animate(i):
    global index
    index+=1
    x.append(index)
    t=1    
    for ydata, line in zip(ydata_set, lines):
        scope.query('*OPC?')
        M=float(scope.query('MEASUrement:MEAS{}:RESUlts:CURRentacq:MEAN?'.format(t)))
        t+=1
        ydata.append(M)
        line.set_data(x, ydata)
```

This will not require the entire subplot to be cleared each time new data comes in.

Comment: You're right plt.cla() was the reason. I just reset the last plot parameters in the animate function. Thanks!

Comment: @PierreDupont Glad it helped, don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so the question is marked as such for future users.